# get data fom txtfile vb.net

Tags: vb.net, generic-list

i'm looking for a method for reading data from a txt file. The text file have this kind of  structure (fixed length fields):

```
0000       AAAAAA     BBBBBB   CCCCCCCC
0000       JJJJJJ     III      RRRRRR
1111       XXXX       YYYYYYYY ZZZZZZZZ
1111       WW         PPPPPPPP ZZZZZZZZ
1111       XXXX       YYYYYYYY ZZZZZZZZ
2222       XXXX       YYYYYYYY ZZZZZZZZ
...
```

I have to get them in groups by first field, in somekind of list of dictionary lists or something like this. For this particular example the solution would be:

```
id(list): 0000,1111,2222.....
(content)List: 0000
    field1(list): AAAAAA,JJJJJJ
    field2(list): BBBBBB,III
    field3(list): CCCCCCCC,RRRRRR
(content)List: 1111
    field1(list): XXXX,WW,XXXX
    field2(list): YYYYYYYY,PPPPPPPP,YYYYYYYY 
    field3(list): ZZZZZZZZ,ZZZZZZZZ,ZZZZZZZZ
(content)List: 2222
    field1(list): XXXX...
    field2(list): YYYYYYYY...
    field3(list): ZZZZZZZZ...
```

Right now i have the the whole txt stored in a list of strings (one per line).

How can i do this in vbnet? Do you think there's a better approach to this problem?

Thanks and have a happy new year

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use [LINQ](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397910.aspx) to create a Dictionary with the first column as key:

```
Dim fileName = "C:\Temp\Test.txt"
Dim allLines = IO.File.ReadAllLines(fileName)

Dim query = From line In allLines
        Select Columns = Microsoft.VisualBasic.Split(line, vbTab)
        Select ID = If(Columns.Count <> 0, Columns(0), " "), Values = Columns.Skip(1).ToList
        Group By ID Into Group
        Select ID, Group

' create a Dictionary from the LINQ-Query '
Dim dict = query.ToDictionary(Function(grp) (grp.ID))
' iterate all Dictionary-Entries '
For Each entry In dict
    Dim key = entry.Key ' f.e 0000 
    For Each grp In entry.Value.Group
        Dim id = grp.ID ' f.e 0000 (can repeat how we see in your example) '
        Dim values As List(Of String) = grp.Values
        ' f.e. (0) "AAAAAA"  (1) "BBBBBB" (2) "CCCCCCCC" '
    Next
Next
```

---

If you are not familiar with LINQ (and you are using .NET 4.0) i would suggest to use a `List(Of Tuple(Of String, List(Of String)))` since duplicates are allowed(dictionary is no option).

```
Dim data = New List(Of Tuple(Of String, List(Of String)))
For Each line In allLines
    Dim Columns = Microsoft.VisualBasic.Split(line, vbTab)
    Dim ID = If(Columns.Count <> 0, Columns(0), "[empty-line]")
    data.Add(Tuple.Create(ID, Columns.ToList))
Next
' iterate the collection and read values '
For Each item In data
    Dim ID = item.Item1
    Dim Columns = item.Item2
Next
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.tuple.aspx

---

**Edit**:

If you cannot use Tuples because you are not using .NET 4.0, try following "oldschool"-approach that creates a `Dictionary(Of String, List(Of List(Of String)))`.

It produces the **exact desired result** (unlike the other ways, because i've misunderstood your requirement a little bit so far):

```
Dim allLines = IO.File.ReadAllLines(fileName)
Dim data As New Dictionary(Of String, List(Of List(Of String)))
For Each line In allLines
    Dim cols = line.Split(ControlChars.Tab)
    Dim ID As String
    If cols.Length <> 0 AndAlso cols(0).Length <> 0 Then
        ID = cols(0)
        If data.ContainsKey(ID) Then
            Dim columnLists = data(ID)
            For colIndex As Int32 = 1 To cols.Length - 1 'skip first(id)-column
                If columnLists.Count >= colIndex Then
                    Dim columnList = columnLists(colIndex - 1)
                    columnList.Add(cols(colIndex))
                Else
                    Dim newColumnList As New List(Of String)
                    newColumnList.Add(cols(colIndex))
                    columnLists.Add(newColumnList)
                End If
            Next
        Else
            Dim columnLists = New List(Of List(Of String))
            For colIndex As Int32 = 1 To cols.Length - 1 'skip first(id)-column
                Dim newColumnList As New List(Of String)
                newColumnList.Add(cols(colIndex))
                columnLists.Add(newColumnList)
            Next
            data.Add(ID, columnLists)
        End If
    End If
Next
```

How you can read the values:

```
Dim idList = data.Keys ' List of all ID-Keys '
For Each id As String In idList
    Dim content As List(Of List(Of String)) = data(id)
    Dim field1List As List(Of String) = content(0)     ' AAAAAA,JJJJJJ
    Dim field2List As List(Of String) = content(1)     ' BBBBBB,III
    ' ....
Next
```

Comment: sounds good but i don't have time enought for learning LINQ right now. Is there any way around? thanks btw

Comment: @bpSz: If i have the time, i'll try to find another approach later. Have you tried to compile above, does it work as expected?

Comment: Seems a good solution, but unfortunaly I'm not using .Net 4.0, could you please translate it into a list of dictionaries of strings or something like this? I can't find the way the get this data. Thanks!

Comment: @bpSz: Last but not least i've provided a way that should also work in 2.0. Have a look at my last edit.

Comment: Thanks! but im facing a new problem wich is that my file doesn't have a field delimiter so I have to get the vars just like this:            AA1 = RTrim(Lines(numLin).Substring(0, 2).ToString)
            TYPEEDOCUMENTATION = RTrim(Lines(numLin).Substring(2, 6).ToString)
            SPONS_CD = RTrim(Lines(numLin).Substring(8, 3).ToString)
            MST_POL = RTrim(Lines(numLin).Substring(11, 15).ToString)          [...]                  Do you know how can i implement this into your code?

Comment: You have a lot of informations that you didn't provide at the first time. I've no time left to get a structure from a unstructured file. I've told you all you need to get the rest done by yourself.

Comment: You should consider to accept the answer so that it gets closed.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the [StreamReader](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.streamreader.aspx#Y0). And do something like this (sorry its in c# but you get the idea):

```
using(StreamReader r = new StreamReader("@C:\somefile.txt"))
{
    while(!r.EndOfStream)
    {
        string line = r.ReadLine();
        string[] data = line.Split(new string[] { "    " }); //use a seperator that is approriate
        //constructor the dictionary yourself
    }
}
```

Edit: Then for your Structure you have a dictionary:

IDictionary - Key: id Value: Truple or create your own tuple class if you don't have access to id as @Tim suggested.

if you can do something rather then using generic I would suggest that.

```
public class Tuple<T,Q,R>
{
    public T First { get; set; }
    public Q Second { get; set; }
    public R Third { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: -1 I'm not sure how this could help the OP to solve his problem.

Comment: @TimSchmelter - According to the original post he was looking for a method to read the text file. You had suggested using LINQ, which he did not like. Therefore I suggested the StreamReader as another way to read the file. The construction of storing would be based on suggestions/OP.

Comment: I haven't used LINQ to read the file, i was always using `IO.File.ReadAllLines`. But apart from that, the OP hasn't problems with reading a file but with interpreting and structuring it and a simple `Split` does not work(not at all after OP told that there is no delimiter).

Comment: @TimSchmelter Ok how I read the problem was based on the first lines of OP that he also needed help reading. The Method I suggested allows easier construction of the objects as each line equivalent of an object. I added how he could store it too.

Comment: Have already suggested Tuples, but he don't use 4.0, also this is a VB.NET question. But anyway, vote balanced :)

Comment: @TimSchmelter yea sorry I meant to credit you on the tuples. I just wanted to post the other mechanism to read the lines. But essentially then since he does not use .net 4.0 he should just create his own tuple class.